# Google cloud system kube-system namespaced deployed daemonsets not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We are having problem with several deployments in our cluster that do not seem to be working. But I am a bit apprehensive in touching these, since they are part of the kube-system namespace. I am also unsure as what the correct approach to getting them into an OK state is.

I currently have two daemonsets that have warnings with the message

**DaemonSet has no nodes selected**

See images below. Does anyone have any idea what the correct approach is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at the DaemonSet objects using `kubectl get daemonset -n kube-system thename -o yaml`. You'll probably see a selector for the GPU one that it only runs on nodes with a GPU and you don't have any?

Comment: I also would like to see the output for `kubectl get daemonset -n kube-system NAME -o yaml` and also for `kubectl describe daemonset -n kube-system NAME` where NAME is your DeamonSet name. Please, can you update your question and include the output for these commands?

Comment: we have the same problem with our gck cluster. Did you solve this?

Comment: @Andreas were you able to solve this issue? Is this still ongoing issue? Could you share steps to replicate this? How did you create this cluster, some IaC scripts in terraform/ansible, via GUI?

Answer (score 1):

A DaemonSet is creating a pod in each node of your Kubernetes cluster.

If the Kubernetes scheduler cannot schedule any pod, there are several possibilities:

- Pod spec has a too high memory requests resource for the memory node capacity, look at the value of `spec.containers[].resources.requests.memory`
- The nodes may have a taint, so DaemonSet declaration must have a toleration ([kubernetes documentation about taint and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/))
- The pod spec may have a `nodeSelector` field ([kubernetes documentation about node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector))
- The pod spec may have an enforced node affinity or anti-affinity ([kubernetes documentation about node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity))
- If [Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) are enabled on the cluster, a security policy may be blocking access to a resource that the pod needs to run

There are not the only solutions possible. More generally, a good start would be to look at the events associated to the daemon set:

```
> kubectl describe daemonsets NAME_OF_YOUR_DAEMON_SET
```